# Impact of repeated failed connection attempts to SQL server express

Tags: sql-server

Does anybody definitively know the impact of failed connection attempts on SQL server express 10.50.2550.0?

Specifically if someone is attempting to hack with an automated system cycling through passwords.

I'm curious to know what level of impact one could expect (CPU, memory/cache usage) - and whether the connection pool is actually affected/mobilised or whether that is only with *successful* connections.

Before anybody comments/asks, action has already been taken to close off the SQL port to any IP other than those approved, so I'm not looking for preventative measures!

Comment: Which version of SQL Server do you use?

Comment: SQL express 10.50.2550.0

Comment: Ah ok. SQL Server 2008 R2. In this edition the impact isn't as big as in the newer versions of SQL Server as their is a new login level (contained databases). Huge connect tries will impact on your SQL Server, but this is a normal behavior as those attempts will always take impact on a system - if the system itself won't ignore request from a special ip. But if you change your port already, I'm sure that the impact won't be to high. Do you use mixed authentication mode or windows only? A mixed mode will decrease the performance too, as there are two sources which needed to be checked.

Comment: The pool is a client-side concept. It will therefore not be affected.

Comment: Would the constant attempts have any detrimental effect on online backups (using the standard SQL backup/restore mechanism)?

Comment: At this point I'm not quite sure. Maybe. But I would thing probably no as the login doesn't succeed. With no login, there won't be a session. Without a session there won't be a lock on the resource.